# parse dates from multiple columns with NAs and dates hidden in text

Tags: r, date, parsing

I have a `data.frame` with dates distributed across columns and in a messy format: the `year` column contains years and `NA`s, the column `date_old` contains the format `Month DD` or `DD` (or a date duration) or `NA`s, and the column `hidden_date` contains text and dates either in thee format `.... YYYY ....` or in the format `.... DD Month YYYY ....` (with `....` representing general text of variable length).

An example `data.frame` looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c("1992", "1993", "1995", NA),
                 date_old = c("February 15", "October 02-24", "15", NA),
                 hidden_date = c(NA, NA, "The hidden date is 15 July 1995", "The hidden date is 2005"))
```

I want to get the dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` (take the first day of date durations) and fill unknown values with zeroes.

Using `parse_date_time` didn't help me so far, and the expected output would be:

```
  year      date_old                     hidden_date        date
1 1992   February 15                            <NA>  1992-02-15
2 1993 October 02-24                            <NA>  1993-10-02
3 1995            15 The hidden date is 15 July 1995  1995-07-15
4 <NA>          <NA>         The hidden date is 2005  2005-00-00
```

How do I best go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little complicated because you have a jumble of date information in different columns which you need to extract and combine. I don't quite understand if you *only* have three columns, or if there could be more, so I've tried to solve the general case of an arbitray number of columns. If you only have three columns, each of which *always* have the same format, then things could be a little simpler, but not much.

I would start by creating a regex pattern for month names:

```
# We'll use dplyr, stringr, tidyr, readr, and purrr
library(tidyverse)

# We'll use month names and abbreviations just in case.
ms <- paste(c(month.name, month.abb), collapse = "|")

# [1] "January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec"
```

We can then iterate over each column, extracting the year, month, and day from each row as a data frame, which we then combine into a single data frame. The digit suffixes correspond to the original columns:

```r
df_split_ymd <- map_dfc(df,
                        ~ map_dfr(
                            .,
                            ~ tibble(
                                year = str_extract(., "\\b\\d{4}\\b"),
                                month = str_extract(., str_glue("\\b({ms})\\b")),
                                day = str_extract(., "\\b\\d{2}\\b")
                                )
                            )
                        )

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 4 x 9
  year  month day   year1 month1   day1  year2 month2 day2 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1 1992  NA    NA    NA    February 15    NA    NA     NA   
2 1993  NA    NA    NA    October  02    NA    NA     NA   
3 1995  NA    NA    NA    NA       15    1995  July   15   
4 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA       NA    2005  NA     NA
```

Finally, the `year*`, `month*`, and `day*` columns should be `coalesce`d and then `unite`d to make parsing easier. Note that I've replaced `NA` values in `day`
 with "01" and those in `month` with "January" because dates can't contain "00":

```r
df_ymd <- df_split_ymd %>% 
    mutate(year = coalesce(!!!as.list(select(., starts_with("year")))),
           month = coalesce(!!!as.list(select(., starts_with("month")))) %>% 
               replace_na("January"),
           day = coalesce(!!!as.list(select(., starts_with("day")))) %>% 
               replace_na("01")
           ) %>% 
    unite(ymd, year, month, day, sep = " ") %>% 
    select(ymd) %>% 
    mutate(ymd = parse_date(ymd, "%Y %B %d"))

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 4 x 1
  ymd       
  <date>    
1 1992-02-15
2 1993-10-02
3 1995-07-15
4 2005-01-01
```

Comment: just one thing: the line `day = str_extract(., "\\b\\d{2}\\b")` also returns matches with numbers like 55, which cannot be dates. (This was not in the question, so you couldn't have known!). To alleviate this, I replaced it by `day = str_extract(., "\\b((?:[1-2][0-9]?|30|31|[1-9]))\\b")` to match only numbers up to 31.